# Label is not showing up

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm building a simple menu from basic Flash UI components using bare ActionScript 3.0, and the very first `Label` control doesn't show up during the movie testing`(Ctrl+Enter)`. Why is that?

I have no symbols in the Library or anything on the stage. My document is linked to *main.as*

What should happen is when the *.swf* is launched `main()` gets the instruction to generate `mainMenu` which in turn will display the only label in the center-top part of the movie screen.

**main.as**

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;

    public class main extends MovieClip{
        public function main(){
            changeState(null, "mainMenu");
        }
        public function changeState(currentState, nextState){
            if(currentState != null){
                removeChild(currentState);
            }
            if(nextState == "mainMenu"){
                var main_menu:mainMenu = new mainMenu(changeState);
                addChild(main_menu);
            }// else if(nextState == "deckManager"){
//              var deck_manager:deckManager = new deckManager(changeState);
//              addChild(deck_manager);
//          }
        }
    }
}
```

**mainMenu.as**

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.controls.Label;
    import fl.controls.RadioButton;
    import fl.controls.ComboBox;
    import fl.controls.Button;

    public class mainMenu extends Sprite{

        const difficultyRadioGroupName:String = "difficultyGroup"; // group name for easy, normal and hard difficulty radio buttons

        var difficultyLabel:Label; // "Difficulty" label
        var easyDifficultyRadio:RadioButton; // "Easy" difficulty radio button
        var normalDifficultyRadio:RadioButton; // "Normal" difficulty radio button
        var hardDifficultyRadio:RadioButton; // "Hard" difficulty radio button
        var yourDeckLabel:Label; // "Your deck" label
        var yourDeckCombo:ComboBox; // combobox to select your deck(1)
        var editSelectedDeckButton:Button; // button to edit currently selected deck
        var startTheGameButton:Button; // button to start the game
        var theCallbackFunction:Function; // callback function to change between mainMenu and deckManager

        public function mainMenu(callback){

            // create and position the difficulty label
            difficultyLabel = new Label();
            difficultyLabel.text = "Difficulty";
            difficultyLabel.x = width / 2;
            difficultyLabel.y = height / 4;
            addChild(difficultyLabel);

            theCallbackFunction = callback;
        }


        //public function backButtonClicked(evt:MouseEvent){
//          theCallbackFunction(this, "back");
//          return;
//      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe everything in the 'fl.controls' package requires the appropriate asset in your library to show up.  If you just import things from fl.controls you get no UI aspect to the control unless you add that element to your library or ingest a swc/swf with the appropriate library assets in it.

So I'd guess that if in the flash IDE, if you dragged the appropriate UI elements from the components tab to your library, they would start showing up.  They don't have to be on the stage or anything, just in the library so the UI elements get compiled with your code.

Comment: Interesting! The Flash IDE (Flash CS5/6 or whatever) is such a different animal than my old friend, Flash Builder :)

Answer (score 1):

On the surface this seems ok.

However, the X/Y coordinates you are assigning to the `Label` might not be what you are expecting. You set them based on the width/height of the `mainMenu` Sprite. But that `Sprite` has no children yet (the child is added on the next line), so the width/height are still 0.

This may not be the problem. To further trouble shoot this I would set some breakpoints and use a debugger, or add a bunch of `trace` statements to make sure your code is executing using the proper values.